# Prevent mousemove fire upon elementFromPoint

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/2FWZD/

Here is jsfiddle code since its force me to add code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.test').on('mousemove', function (e) {
        counter++;
        $('.counter').text(counter);

        $(this).hide();
        // Comment out the following line and counter will stop increasing
        document.elementFromPoint(e.clientX, e.clientY);
        $(this).show();
    });
});
```

This happens in chrome, is there anyway to prevent this or an alternative method to elementFromPoint ?

Bug detailed here: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=333623

---

Edit 1:

I just want to note while the answer is a cleaver hack to the jsfiddle demo it doesn't actually solve the underlying issue I have.

I am using Leap Motion to simulate a mouse on a website which sends simulated mousedown and mouseup events and also mousemoves. I use a canvas to draw the cursor on top of everything and use the technique shown here to access the element that is just underneath the canvas. Upon doing that the mousemove is triggered at the REAL mouse location and not my simulated mouse, effectively giving me weird issues.

This isn't an issue for FireFox.

---

Edit 2:

Issue Solves. See Answer. Using other methods of hiding besides hide() seem to work without triggering

Comment: Doesn't happen to me in Chrome. If you have a problem with a specific browser you need to mention which version and which System. And additionally you should explain why you need to `hide` and then immediately `show` the element again, because this doesn't make sense without any context.

Comment: I'm seeing the bug in chrome. When I delete `.hide()` method everything works like expected.

Comment: I can reproduce the bug on Chrome 40.0.2214.115 for OS X.

Comment: I also cannot reproduce in Chrome 40 on OS X. Also, what is the significance of calling `hide` then `show`?

Comment: I would guess you could solve that with  `pointer-events: none` on that element, instead of showing and hiding it. That should also increase the performance of your application as it would not require the layout engine do unnecessary tasks.

Comment: What is the reason to hide the '.test'?

Comment: Didn't know about `pointer-events`. Good to know, one issue though is that I also simulate mouseover events and there is no way for javascript to trigger :hover css so I have to find what the mouse is over and manually add a class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just keep last position, something like this:

```
var counter = 0;
var last='';
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.test').on('mousemove', function (e) {
        var cur=e.screenX+':'+e.screenY;
        if (cur == last) return;
        last = cur;
        counter++;
        $('.counter').text(counter);

        $(this).hide();
        // Comment out the following line and counter will stop increasing
        document.elementFromPoint(e.clientX, e.clientY);
        $(this).show();
    });
});
```

other way it seems is to hide an element by making it "invisible" using css:

```
var counter = 0;

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.test').on('mousemove', function (e) {
        counter++;
        $('.counter').text(counter);

        $(this).addClass('hidden');
        // Comment out the following line and counter will stop increasing
        console.log(document.elementFromPoint(e.clientX, e.clientY));
        $(this).removeClass('hidden');
    });
});
```

css:

```
.test.hidden {
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2FWZD/10/

Comment: @Nit why not ? that fine while i sure that one of the strings has ":"

Comment: You should use `localeCompare`, or at least `===`.

Comment: I know what you mean, why in **this particular case** ?

Comment: You should do it in every case.

Comment: if you are 100% sure that both parts of the comparison are both strings (in this case it is) then `==` is fine.

Comment: I believe your 2nd answer solves the -real- issue I had (see edit of question). Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`elementFromPoint()` will return the element for specific coordinates. In this case the element under the pointer/cursor. In the example code the `elementFromPoint()` function returns `<html>` because `.test` is hidden. For some reason this is causing Chrome to think that the mouse is moving. However you can use `querySelectorAll(":hover")` instead of `elementFromPoint()`.

[jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kasperfish/2FWZD/12/)

```
var counter = 0;

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.test').not( "body" ).on('mousemove', function (e) {
        counter++;
        $('.counter').text(counter);

        $(this).hide();

        // Comment out the following line and counter will stop increasing
        var el=document.querySelectorAll( ":hover" ); //el = html not .test because it is hidden
        console.log(el);
        $(this).show();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a possible reason why the problem is happening:

Browsers optimize for as few redraws as possible to offer a smoother viewing experience. This means that when possible, blocks like these

```
$(this).hide();
$(this).show();
```

Are optimized out to simply be no-op when possible. This however is not the case when a redraw is forced between the two operations, as is the case with, for example, your code

```
$(this).hide();
document.elementFromPoint(e.clientX, e.clientY);
$(this).show();
```

or, as is sometimes used as a hack to avoid the optimization when unneeded

```
$(this).hide();
this.offsetHeight;
$(this).show();
```

It seems that showing the element again triggers `mousemove` on Chrome under certain circumstances.

Comment: I don't think Chrome will optimize the `hide`/`show` pair away.  But yes for certain actions the layout engine needs to do a internal _relayout_ , basically  everything where you need to retrieve some layout information, like `document.elementFromPoint` and `this.offsetHeight`.On the other side logging `$(this).get(0).style.display` between them will show the correct value without triggering a refresh.

Answer (score 1):

#### In short

Don't use $(element).hide() . Chrome has issues (and becomes our new IE6).

Instead of that just handout css yourse, that you don't want to show the .test - element, when trying to do a getElementFromPoint

[See solution in jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Drifter/od4pxazy/)

#### The long version

Chrome at this point can't handle 'display:none' in CSS and wil redraw the total element. This will set off the mousemove-event and thus will it become an everlasting cycle.

Instead of using display:none, you can also just make the *'height'* zero which will have the same effect for selecting the right element.
Out of this, I made a function fastDraw

.hide() becomes fastDraw

```
function fastDraw($box, show){
    if(show){
        $box.css({'height': $box.data('height')});
    } else {
        $box.data('height', $box.height());
        $box.css({'height': 0});
    }
}
```

Now you get the same results

```
fastDraw($box); //hides the element by setting the height zero
var element = document.elementFromPoint(e.clientX, e.clientY); //fetches the element
fastDraw($box, true); //return it back to the previous height
```

#### Optimization

Since you are using the mouseMove event, it will be called a lot times and it is best to do at little as possible. I've refactored some stuff, so it will do less calculation.

Comment: I think such optimisation is not needed here because biggest Issue would be the layout recalculation. If you need it really optimize use throttling or debouncing.

Comment: like this http://jsfiddle.net/od4pxazy/3/ (100 is too much, just to make a feeling of the effect)

Comment: Than the counter becomes a lot less 'live'

Comment: you almost never need to catch all mousemove events, only thing is bad with my sample is that it not catch "last" event, but it could be fixed, jsfiddle.net/od4pxazy/5